# Unknown error in bootloader during unlock after crash

Tags: fastboot, bootloader, bootloader-lock

With my ACER a700, Android crashed. Now, each time I turn it on it starts in fastboot mode. I tried to unlock bootloader to install Cyanogen, but after command line I have an response like **"Error: Unknown error"**.

Is there a possibility to reset completely the device in order to reinstall a ROM?

EDIT:

I downloaded rom from [this link](http://chinagadgetsreviews.blogspot.fr/2014/04/download-stock-firmware-android-40-ics.html?m=1) and move *update.zip* onto SD card. I would boot in recovery mode but I can't, because of bootloader. I have the following output:

```
Booting failed
Bootloader vJB-663b3d3: Starting Fastboot USB download protocol
```

It seems I have not recovery menu. Also, I can't doing 'factory reset', I have the same failed.

Comment: Did you try flashing a stock firmware?

Comment: Thank for your answer @esQmo! No, I didn't. How could I do this?

Comment: Check my answer. And did you try `fastboot -w` conmand to reset the device?

Comment: I did not try `fastboot -w`, I did try to unlock bootloader. What should it do?

Comment: It will reset the phone and reboots.

Comment: I just tried `fastboot -w`, it does not work because bootloader is locked. I'll try your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be solved by flashing stock firmware to your device.

Download the firmware and flashing tool from [here](http://droid-developers.com/acer-iconia-tab-a700-official-stock-firmware-flashing-tools/).

Edited: [List of A700 ROMs](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1720157) and updates from XDA Developers + Flashing procedure.

- Another download [links](http://chinagadgetsreviews.blogspot.com/2014/04/download-stock-firmware-android-40-ics.html?m=1)

Comment: I'll try to do this. I just need to download one zip, right?

Comment: Just one zip file.

Comment: Have you tried? I'm trying to download one of the ZIP, but I have the following error on the website:
`

The public file you are trying to download is associated with a non-valid account.

Please contact the owner for further assistance.
`

Comment: No, I didn't download any file.

Comment: It seems files are no longer available because of owner account.

Comment: Check my edited answer

Comment: I'll try it now. But with un a locked bootloader, will I can install a ROM ?

Comment: Yes, those ROMs can be flashed on a a phone with locked bootloader. Just follow the process.

Comment: Links seems unreachable.. I'll search others.

Comment: I'm not on a computer, I can't test the links.

Comment: Try these links: http://chinagadgetsreviews.blogspot.com/2014/04/download-stock-firmware-android-40-ics.html?m=1

Comment: It worked. I've edited my question to explain why I can't reboot in recovery